# slice list with if else condition using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, slice

I want the list to has only number that is not 1 [3,4,5] and put the 1 into another list. below is the code i write

```
a_list=[1,1,1,1,3,4,5]
one_list=[]
a_list[:] = [a if a != 1 else one_list.append(a) for a in a_list]
print(a_list)
print(one_list)
```

here is the output for a_list -
[None, None, None, None, 3, 4, 5]

my desired output for a_list - [3, 4, 5]

Comment: You are adding the result of `append` (i.e. `None`) in the else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first part of the question, the correct comprehension would be:

```
[e for e in a_list if e != 1]
```

For what you want to do, a comprehension is not really the right tool, use a classical loop:

```
a_list=[1,1,1,1,3,4,5]

list1 = []
list2 = []
for e in a_list:
    if e == 1:
        list1.append(e)
    else:
        list2.append(e)
```

output:

```
>>> list1
[1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> list2
[3, 4, 5]
```

##### what you wanted to do and why you should not:

what you tried to do with the comprehension is:

```
a_list=[1,1,1,1,3,4,5]
one_list = []
a_list[:] = [e for e in a_list if (True if e != 1 else one_list.append(e))]
a_list, one_list
```

However, you should not as it does not prevent making a temporary list, and it is not explicit/pythonic.

###### bonus: using itertools

```
from itertools import tee, filterfalse

def partition(pred, iterable):
    "Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries"
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)

a_list=[1,1,1,1,3,4,5]
a_list, one_list = map(list, partition(lambda x: x == 1, a_list))
```

Comment: You can always run `a_list[:] = list1` at the end, in any case the comprehension does **not** prevent making a temporary list

Comment: There's also the `partition` function in the [`itertools` documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html): `list1, list2 = map(list, partition(lambda x: x == 1, a_list))`. No temporary lists are created, but there is buffering of the elements of `a_list` due to the use of `tee` in the definition of `partition`.

Comment: If you want to get fancy with the regular loop, you can define `a = {True: list1.append, False: list2.append}`, then reduce the loop body to `a[e==1](e)`.

Comment: `itertools` is always nice, I'll add it as comment, the second idea is nice but maybe not explicit enough for such a simple case ;)

Comment: Sometimes I'll just predefine something like `f = list1.append; g = list2.append` to avoid the attribute lookup inside the loop. I'll stop bike-shedding now :) The loop is the right solution here.

Comment: OK, one more interesting tidbit: you can define `f = [].append; g = [].append`, then use `list1 = f.__self__; list2 = g.__self__` to recover the anonymous lists modified by the two bound methods in the body of the loop. Or what my second comment *should* have been: `(list1 if e == 1 else list2).append(e)`.

Comment: I see you like hacky stuff, (love it too), just hope you don't use this in production code :p

Comment: I probably *would* use my final suggestion in production code. :)

Comment: The final one (`(list1 if e == 1 else list2).append(e)`) is fine, I was talking about the `list1 = f.__self__` ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's disgusting.